# How to compare 2 json to find new entries with depth?

Tags: php, arrays, json, compare

I want to compare 2 json and if there is new array  it will get the new array and insert it to the database.

This is the old json,

```
[{"menu_id":"1","menu_name":"Rapat 2018","parent_id":"0","link":"informent.online","status":"1"},
{"menu_id":"3","menu_name":"Rapat 2019","parent_id":"0","link":"#","status":"1"}]
```

This is the new json,

```
[{"menu_id":"1","menu_name":"Rapat 2018","parent_id":"0","link":"informent.online","status":"1","children":[{"menu_id":"","menu_name":"Rapat RW","parent_id":"1","link":"#","status":"1"}]},
{"menu_id":"3","menu_name":"Rapat 2019","parent_id":"0","link":"#","status":"1"}]
```

There is new array from children (menu_name : Rapat RW), I want to get that new array so i can insert it to the database.

This is what i have done,

```
$json_str1 = '  [
                      {
                        "menu_id": "1",
                        "menu_name": "Rapat 2018",
                        "parent_id": "0",
                        "link": "informent.online",
                        "status": "1"
                      },
                      {
                        "menu_id": "3",
                        "menu_name": "Rapat 2019",
                        "parent_id": "0",
                        "link": "#",
                        "status": "1"
                      }
                    ]';
    $json_str2 = '  [
                      {
                        "menu_id": "1",
                        "menu_name": "Rapat 2018",
                        "parent_id": "0",
                        "link": "informent.online",
                        "status": "1",
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "menu_id": "",
                            "menu_name": "Rapat RW",
                            "parent_id": "1",
                            "link": "#",
                            "status": "1"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "menu_id": "3",
                        "menu_name": "Rapat 2019",
                        "parent_id": "0",
                        "link": "#",
                        "status": "1"
                      }
                    ]';

    list($arr1, $arr2) = [json_decode($json_str1), json_decode($json_str2)];
    $common_items = array_intersect($arr2, $arr1);
    $result = array_filter(array_merge($arr1, $arr2), function($v) use($common_items){
        return !in_array($v, $common_items);
    });

    print_r($result);
```

But i return error "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" from "Function: array_intersect"
What is the problem?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far and what did not work about that. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service but a platform to help you solve concrete issues. Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: decode json, then check `children` exist or not ? if exist compare children of old and new data only and based on that get new array what you finally have to insert into db

Comment: `[json_decode($json_str1), json_decode($json_str2)]` needs to be `[json_decode($json_str1,true), json_decode($json_str2,true)]`

Comment: now it return "Array to string conversion"

Comment: that does happens somewhere else, it don't see array to string in your code, you have more relevant code?

Comment: array_intersect($arr2, $arr1);
This code give me error "Array to string conversion", Is it because the array has depth?

Answer (score 0):

I see array_intersect compares values as string. Thus the array to string error. Because on of your values is an array itself. To solve this you must use `array_uintersect`

http://php.net/array_uintersect

```
function myFunction($value1, $value2) {
    //compare and return 1 or 0
    return (int) $value1 !== $value2; //for example
}
$common_items = array_uintersect($arr2, $arr1, "myFunction");
```